# Does anyone know what this yellow underline is coming from? Error message says it's due to "dead code" but I defined the local variable?

Tags: java, dead-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx2oM.png)[enter image description here][2]I have tried getting rid of the local variable and making i increment but x.length() but that produces a yellow underline as well. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
public static boolean isCat(String s, String x) {
    int xlen = x.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += xlen) {
        if (s.substring(0, i).equals(x)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx2oM.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] the question and include the code as text, not as image.

Comment: When you hover over the yellow line with your mouse cursor, what is the warning saying?

Comment: On first iteration `i=0`, so `substring(0, i)` returns an empty string. If `"".equals(x)` the method returns `true`. If not, the method returns `false`. The method never gets to the second iteration of the loop. As written, the method might as well be `return x.isEmpty();`

Answer (score 3):

Because your loop will `return` true or false before the increment step. Thus the increment is "dead code". Move `return false;` **after** the loop body. Or,

```
public static boolean isCat(String s, String x) {
    return s.contains(x);
}
```